# .eps files not working with pdfLaTeX

Tags: floats, pdftex, eps, shell-escape, epstopdf

As the title suggests, I'm trying to use .eps files for my figures but pdfLaTeX can't seem to find the converted PDFs.

```
Package pdftex.def: File `Figures/fragment 1ab-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
```

I'm on a Windows machine using Miktex and Visual Studio Code with Latex Workshop. I turned on -shell-escape, as well as Write18.

When I use `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in my code explicitly, it just generates an empty image:
[image]

I tried searching for the generated PDFs, but I can't seem to find them. Running XeTeX instead of pdftex makes .eps usable but generates other issues with fonts.

When I run my minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}{./}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{Figures/fragment 1ab.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get a `Sorry, but miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted did not succeed.` in my console, and it doesn't generate a PDF (works fine if I use a PNG instead of a .eps). It also redirects me to a log file which reads:

```
2023-11-13 14:23:21,678+0100 INFO  miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - this process (19964) started by cmd in directory c:\Latex\Templates\minimal example with command line: miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted --outfile=Figures/fragment 1ab-eps-converted-to.pdf Figures/fragment 1ab.eps
2023-11-13 14:23:21,678+0100 INFO  miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - running on Windows 10.0.19045
2023-11-13 14:23:21,767+0100 FATAL miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - Too many input files.
2023-11-13 14:23:21,768+0100 FATAL miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - Too many input files.
2023-11-13 14:23:21,768+0100 FATAL miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - Info: 
2023-11-13 14:23:21,768+0100 FATAL miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - Source: 
2023-11-13 14:23:21,768+0100 FATAL miktex-epstopdf-unrestricted - Line: 0
```

Comment: do not use spaces in file names.

Comment: The `graphicx` package loads the `epstopdf` package automatically.  Incidentally, why do you write `\includegraphics{Figures/fragment 1ab.eps}`? Why not write `\includegraphics{Figures/fragment 1ab}`?

Comment: you do not need `--shell-escape`. As Ulrike says avoid spaces in filenames, but also if possible generate pdf rather than eps from your original application. pdflatex can not include postscript files so they have to be converted using epstopdf so it's much simpler if you generate pdf rather than eps to start with.